# Is there a initalSetup() function or something like that in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have developed an app in Laravel (and i used this plugin to add roles/permissions https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

I need to create some basic data for my app in Laravel only the first time the app is used (a few roles and permissions), this data shouldnt be created every time.

I couldnt find a function or event which i could use.
Im trying to avoid doing:

```
if(role is not created)
    create it
else
    do nothing
```

Comment: If you are talking about seeding then read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding)

Comment: If you are talking about how to use mysql cli then read the [basic tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial) _(no way, seeding way more easier)_

Answer (score 1):

To setup basic app data or seeding start by creating a seeder:

```
php artisan make:seeder RolesTableSeeder
```

It will generate `database/seeder/RolesTableSeeder.php`, open that file then insert your initial roles, here is the example:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RolesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('roles')->truncate();

        $roles = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Administrator',
                'slug' => 'admin',
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Moderator',
                'slug' => 'moderator',
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            ],
        ];

        DB::table('roles')->insert($roles);
    }
}
```

Then register the seeder on `DatabaseSeeder`class:

```
public function run()
{
    ...

    $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Finally run `php artisan db:seed`, do the same for other tables.

If you want to inserting fake data such as fake users for testing purpose use [model factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#model-factories).